# How to identify dynamic WebElement to upload the picture using Java and Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to identify this button to click on it and upload the picture.
When checking my Xpath, it identifies it (even when page is refreshed) but when executing the code - nothing happens.
Tried to SendKeys with the path to the file or identify coordinates of this element and click on coordinates - neither worked
WebElement -> AddPhoto

```
    //DISABLE CHROME NOTIFICATIONS
    
                    // Create object of HashMap Class
            Map<String, Object> prefs = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                  
                    // Set the notification setting it will override the default setting
            prefs.put("profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications", 2);
     
                    // Create object of ChromeOption class
            ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
     
                    // Set the experimental option
            options.setExperimentalOption("prefs", prefs);
     
                    // pass the options object in Chrome driver
    

    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium-Facebook\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);   
        driver.get("https://www.facebook.com/marketplace");
        driver.manage().window().maximize();

        
    //ENTER CREDENTIALS
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='email']")).sendKeys("login@email.com");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='pass']")).sendKeys("password");
    

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='pass']")).sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);     
    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/marketplace/create/' and  @aria-label='Create New Listing']")).click();
    
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@href='/marketplace/create/item/']")).click(); 
    
    //Create new listing 
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Create New Listing']")).click();
    

    //Where the issues begin
    
    //WebElement AddPhoto = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//i[@data-visualcompletion ='css-img' and contains(@style,'u4NKNaueohq.png')]/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div/parent::div"));
    
    WebElement AddPhoto = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@accept='image/*,image/heif,image/heic']/parent::*/following-sibling::div[1]/child::div[1]/child::div[1]"));
    //AddPhoto.sendKeys("path to the file");

    
    // Create an object of Actions class and pass reference variable driver as a parameter to its constructor. 
     Actions actions = new Actions(driver); 

// Get the location and Coordinate (x, y) of WebElement. Call getLocation(), getX(), and getY() methods to find the location and coordinate. 
     int getX = AddPhoto.getLocation().getX(); 
    
     int getY = AddPhoto.getLocation().getY(); 

// Call moveByOffset() method of Actions class to move the mouse cursor from initial position to given Offset. 
// Pass the coordinates of x and y as parameters to moveByOffset() method. 
     actions.moveByOffset(getX+1, getY+1).click(); 
     actions.build().perform();
```

[WebElement trying to identify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YNHML.jpg)

[Code used to create selectors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zgnwS.jpg)

Comment: Is there any `input` field in entire webpage ?

Answer (score 1):

```
 //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@aria-label='Create New Listing']")).click();

 The above XPath element was showing the staleElementReferenceException so, handled it with the below explicit wait 
 
new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.refreshed(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//*[contains(text(),'Create New Listing')]")))).click();


WebElement AddPhoto = driver.findElement(By.xpath("((//*[@class='mkhogb32'])[1])"));
AddPhoto.sendKeys("File path");


You can check with the above XPath to send the file path
```

Answer (score 0):

I see, there are `2 input field` with type as a file.

so you can surely do this to upload a file :-

```
WebElement AddPhoto = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[type='file']"));
AddPhoto.sendKeys("path to the file");
```